# Weechat with the beep script is not making sounds

Tags: windows-7, audio, cygwin, weechat

I had a friend help me configure `weechat-curses`, version 0.4.2 in Cygwin. Got to where I wanted to set a custom sound for highlights with [beep.pl](http://weechat.org/scripts/source/beep.pl.html/). I set the command to run on highlight to `cat /cygdrive/$path_to_wav_file > /dev/dsp`. It doesn't seem to work, though, even if I set the command back to the default of `$bell`.

Now I was told about ogg123 being able to play sounds inside of Cygwin. I asked a similar question on the Cygwin forums and [their responses were](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/beep-perl-script-td105073.html).

> There was a problem with /dev/dsp in a recent release (1.7.26) of 
>   cygwin1.dll.  That was fixed in version 1.7.27. 
>   http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2013-12/msg00009.html.  Make 
>   sure that your installation is up to date.

and

> Don't know why >/dev/dsp does not work (I get just noise), but you can use
>   ogg123 (ogg-vorbis) and play for example .oga-files:
>
> ```
> ogg123 alarm-clock-elapsed.oga
> ```
>
> That works for me on 1.7.20. It's been a while since I played with sound-output, don't know if you can play wav-files from inside cygwin at all.

How would I go about setting it with ogg123 `.oga` files? He mentions that

> It's been a while since I played with sound-output, don't know if you can play wav-files from inside cygwin at all.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Try making it log when you get pinged. Set the command to `date >>/tmp/bell-test` or something. Also, make sure the `cat $wav_file >/dev/dsp` actually works: try it in a shell.

Comment: Okay thanks to your help and the help of others I have sound pining me now BUT I had to do it another way per your help. Using that ogg123 but it will not play the complete .ogg file and it had to be different from my default system beep file.

Comment: `beep.pl` has a `beep_command_timeout` option. Check that and adjust if necessary. It needs to be as long as the duration of the audio file, and any overhead that `ogg123` has (`time` might come in handy here). Please also post the solution as an answer to your question (and accept it, once you can) so that others may benefit from it. :)

Comment: The beep_Command_timeout option should be set default to plenty long enough, 30,000 milliseconds is 30 seconds. The file itself is only 3 seconds long.

Comment: I think it is cygwin itself because doing the command cat /pathhere/file.wav >/dev/dsp works if it is not the default windows beep sound. But again it cuts the file off.

Comment: It'd be a pretty serious bug in Cygwin if it's imposing a timeout on commands. Although that's pretty easy to disprove by trying to run `sleep 15` or something. You can [run `dtrace` to see if `ogg123` is being signalled](https://superuser.com/a/480933/144700) before it finishes. (Alternately, you could replace it with a wrapper script that catches and logs signals.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the sound file being used. Serious, I tested it again with another file and it worked. The ogg123 software worked as well. So what I did was made sure that the wav file actually worked in shell, which the first one would not. So I tried another one and it worked. Then I told Cygwin to use that file for the beep on highlight by using the [ cat /cygdrive/path to file/wavfile >/dev/dsp/ ] The new wav file worked.

As for ogg123, playing the orignal wav file did not work so I converted it to ogg format and it still did not work. So i tested it with the other wav file and it worked.

My conclusion is this. If you are trying to use the default system beep as your beep on highlight option in weechat through cygwin, then it will not work. Needs further testing to be sure.